# Localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE , Nodejs error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I just started learning Node.js, but I'm stuck on a server issue. I tried all sorts of solutions but they didn't work (changed port, updated node.js, updated chrome, etc) but nothing has worked.

THE SERVER OPENS BUT LOCALHOST DOES NOT RESPOND.

**Here is my index.js file**

```
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("test");
  res.send("Hello world");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server open port ${port}`);
});
```

**Here is my package.json file**

```
  "name": "last-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

**Terminal views**

```
$ node app.js
Server open port 3000
test
test
test
test
```

**The server starts but didn't get a response by localhost in Chrome. The same code works in my friends device though. **

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Did you import the module?

```
const express = require('express');
const port = 3003;
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log("test");
    res.send("Hello world");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server open port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Note: I changed port as I use port 3000 frequently in other node apps

Comment: You shouldn't supplement your answer in comments. Please improve it by editing.

Comment: You are close?? What that means?? Yes I import the npm package Express both imported but still not get any response

Comment: @AkhilRana, I only added the first line to what you had, and thus, I say you were close. You installed the package, but that is not the same as importing the expess module for node to use. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/modules.html#modules_modules